# How to use NPAPI plugin in Windows 7 Gadget?

Tags: javascript, npapi, windows-desktop-gadgets

Have a nice day!
How to use NPAPI plugin written on C++ in Windows 7 desktop gadget? Any examples or suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most certainly cannot do this. IE and related technologies haven't supported NPAPI since IE 4 (or something around there).

You *might* be able to use an ActiveX control. I'm not sure.

(alright, when I say you can't do this, I'm sure you could create a NPAPI host that lives in a gadget or something and load the plugin there, but that seems a little silly)

Comment: I want to create a little gadget for our company proxy/ This gadget help to keep connection alive and view status of connection with proxy. Can I do something like that to make in clean javascript?

Comment: I don't know; that would probably be best as a new question.